# What is the browser support of an svg mask and how to get maximal browser support

Tags: svg, cross-browser

I have been making an image slider with svg. I used masks to animate the transitions. I ran into an issue where the animation isn't working on mobile. So I started looking into browser support of the mask attribute, since I expect that is the cause of the issue. Most sites show browser support for desktop browsers, but not for mobile browsers.

- In what (mobile)browsers are svg masks **not** supported?
- Is there any way to improve cross-browser-support for svg masks?
- Would it be possible to detect whether a browser supports masks with javascript (so I can create a fallback without animations for those browsers)?

Answer (score 0):

You can test for feature support in SVG markup with the [`<switch>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SwitchElement) element. If the UA supports masks, only the first group will be rendered, if not, only the second.

```
<switch>
    <g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Mask">
        <!-- content that needs mask capability -->
    </g>
    <g>
        <!-- fallback content here -->
    </g>
</switch>
```

**Important:** What you need to enclose with the switch are elements that are actually to be rendered. Since the `<mask>` element is not rendered but only referenced, the switch will have no effect. Instead enclose the rendered element that gets the `mask` attribute/style property.

While there was also a [DOMImplementation.hasFeature()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/hasFeature) method, it is now deprecated and may not return helpfull values.

Comment: Pretty much all UAs report all features as supported, even unknown ones.

Comment: @ccprog Thx for taking the time to reply. DOMImplementation.hasFeature() seemed to be exactly what I was looking for. Very unfortunate that it is being depricated. Adding in a switch element will add some more complexity to my svg generating javascript, which I'd rather avoid. Is there any javascript alternative to DOMImplementation.hasFeature()? Any idea why this function is being depricated?

Comment: It's been depricated because it was useless. Browser manufacturers didn't know when to enable the switches. If you support almost all aspects of masks except one should you set the switch true or false. What if you've known bugs in masks, is the switch true or false? etc etc. switches use hasFeature internally and you will find they don't do feature testing either any more.